# Test Class for Redirecting Users to Different Visualforce Pages by Record Type

Tags: apex, visualforce, unit-test

On Jeff Douglas's [blog post on redirecting users to different Visualforce pages depending on the object's record type](http://blog.jeffdouglas.com/2008/11/14/redirecting-users-to-different-visualforce-pages/), there are several comments asking: How can I write a test class for the Visualforce page controllers?

Here is the Visualforce page code Jeff posted to replace the View standard button (I replaced references to Contact w/sObject):

```
<apex:page standardController="sObject" extensions="DispatchersObjectViewController"  
action="{!nullValue(redir.url, urlFor($Action.sObject.Edit, sObject.id, null, true))}">
```

And here's the controller:

```
public class DispatchersObjectViewController {

public DispatchersObjectViewController(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {
    this.controller = controller;
}

public PageReference getRedir() {
    Id RecordTypeId1 = Schema.SObjectType.sObject.getRecordTypeInfosByName().get('Record Type Name').getRecordTypeId();
    Id RecordTypeId2 = Schema.SObjectType.sObject.getRecordTypeInfosByName().get('Record Type Name').getRecordTypeId();

    sObject obj= [Select id, recordtypeid From sObject Where Id = :ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id')];

    PageReference newPage;

    if (sObject.recordtypeid == RecordTypeId1) {
        newPage = Page.RecordTypeId1page;
    } else {
        newPage = Page.RecordTypeId2page;
    } 


    newPage.getParameters().put('id', sObject.Id);
    return newPage.setRedirect(true);

}

private final ApexPages.StandardController controller;

}
```

Comment: And your question? If it is writing the code for you, sorry, you got the wrong place. If you have attempted it and are having issue, then we would be glad to help

Comment: Maybe I posted this in the wrong place, but this is what Stackexchange sent me to when giving me the option to post a solution to a problem I found. There have been a lot of requests for a test class to provide code coverage for the VF page redirect in the post I linked to above. I'm happy to take it down or post it somewhere else. I just thought it would be useful for others to have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the test class:

```
@isTest
private class TestDispatchersObjectViewController {
@isTest static void testsObjectView(){
    sObject obj = new sObject();
    obj.RecordTypeId = Schema.SObjectType.Campaign.getRecordTypeInfosByName().get('Record Type Name').getRecordTypeId();
    obj.Name = 'Test';
    insert obj;

    Test.setCurrentPageReference(new PageReference('Page.myPage'));
    System.currentPageReference().getParameters().put('Id', obj.Id);

    ApexPages.StandardController sc = new ApexPages.standardController(obj);
    DispatchersObjectViewController controller = new DispatchersObjectViewController(sc);       

    controller.getRedir();


}
}
```

Comment: Um. Did you intend to post this as a Q&A?

Comment: There are few if any generally applicable learns here. This test doesn't even verify your behavior matches the spec. If this is all you've got, I'm going to have to vote to close.

Comment: Maybe I posted this in the wrong place, but this is what Stackexchange sent me to when giving me the option to post a solution to a problem I found. There have been a lot of requests for a test class to provide code coverage for the VF page redirect in the post I linked to above. I'm happy to take it down or post it somewhere else. I just thought it would be useful for others to have.

Comment: Coverage is not the only thing. You should look at [How to Write Good Unit Tests](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/How_to_Write_Good_Unit_Tests) and **[smoke testing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smoke_testing#Smoke_testing_in_software_development)**. Normally I would -1 for someone who recommended a coverage solution with no assertions. It totally misses the point.  I realize you were just trying to help here but this example perpetuates **bad habits**.

Comment: See also: [How to Write Good Unit Tests](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/apex_testing/apex_testing_intro). I must reiterate the above is *not* a good test. But it may be a good learning experience for you if you take advantage of the opportunity.